# How can I edit an edit suggestion on mobile?

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

I recently tried to improve an edit suggestion. Yet on mobile the layout seems broken to me. The text field does not allow to scroll further left and any OK or submit button seems inaccessible. Zoom is also unavailable. I can scroll to the right, but no active submit button there.

[image]

Comment: Can you [add](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/376393/edit) the platform (incl. version) and web browser (incl. version)? Are you using the old Stack Exchange app (not a web browser)?

Comment: I'm using chrome 98 on android 12